# Can I give a book as a present to one of my bosses now he is retiring?

Tags: professionalism, social-nuances, retirement

One of the owners of the company I work for is retiring. He always goes out of his way to be kind to people, and since I'm very shy I've always found very reassuring knowing he was in the company's management, although I have never worked in the department he was in charge of.

I'd love to be able to give him a book as a token of my appreciation, but I lack social abilities big time, and I'm not sure if being given books by random employees can be awkward for him (the last thing I want is to upset him).

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with this site.

Comment: Yeah, this one: https://www.astrokatie.com/book :) I really think he'll enjoy it.

Comment: I really like the words you used in your question, and I suggest that you also use them when handing over the book. Personally, I'd be *very* flattered if someone told me *"you always went out of your way to be kind to people. I've always found it very reassuring knowing that you are in the company's management, even though I have never worked directly in your department"*.

Comment: I think giving a book is a very good gesture, and will be fondly seen by the person you gift it to. However for this particular title ("the end of everything") isn't there a non-small chance that it could be linked to the idea of retiring? (even though the subject is cosmology, the title in itself seems a bit darker if one takes it as a parallel to what happens after the end of his carreer?)

Comment: (following) however if you think it will be enjoyed, it could be even better better. Otherwise, if you like science, some books that can be enjoyed both from people who know science or who doesn't: the biography of Richard Feynman "Surely you're joking mr Feynman" is a GREAT read. But of course offer a book that you know and enjoy and think that person will enjoy (which is probably ehat your choice was!)

Comment: If the person is someone dear to you or you simply just appreciate them, there is nothing wrong with a gift. Just consider getting something that you know they are interested in as it will make the gift feel more personal

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> I'm not sure if being given books by random employees can be awkward for him

Certainly not, I think it's a nice gesture if you want to give them a book, so I doubt it would be awkward or frowned upon.

Something along the lines of *"Hello, Joe. I greatly appreciate your support during this time, it's been very valuable to me. I saw this book I think you'll like, and I decided to give it to you as a token of my gratitude."*

Feel free to elaborate as much or as few as you want/feel like.

Comment: If you are awkward in person, I'd pre-write out what you want to say on a note or card (or on the inside of the book), so way you can properly communicate what you want to express when you're not under the stress of in-person communication. You can either leave the book, wrapped with a ribbon or in wrapping paper, with his secretary or on his desk, or hand it to him in person with a very short verbal exchange, e.g., "I hope you enjoy your retirement!" as you hand them the book, with your actual thoughts pre-written inside it or in a gift card on top of it (tied on with the ribbon).

Comment: @JaminGrey I'd hardly second to write this on the first blank page, I feel this is too rarely done nowadays, but books last longer than cards and are definitely more often picked up. I really enjoy finding old books that my parents gave me and be reminded of the occasion and warm words and if your boss likes the book, he'll have a beautiful personal touch to picking it up again after some years.

Answer (score 48):

The general rule is that gifts should flow down the organisation chart, and not up it. However, if someone is leaving or retiring, and it's someone who you care about then it's absolutely fine for you to give them a small gift - and I'm sure that they'll appreciate it. Don't make a big deal of it - just speak to them privately at some point, say that you've really appreciated them (or whatever), and give them the book.

Oh, and make sure it's not a book like "How to lose weight" or "How to be a better boss", unless you know them *really, really* well.

Comment: This randomly reminded me that when I finished grade 4, my teacher left the school and we made goodbye cards for her. Not understanding the concept of work, I taped a quarter in mine and wrote, "To help pay for your new job."

Comment: In what country is this the "general rule"? I've been in a fair few positions in the UK and I wouldn't think twice about getting a gift for someone more senior than me, whether it be a birthday gift or a leaving present. The idea that there is some "rule" around this I find quite chilling - are your organisations that rigid with hierarchy? Good bosses will treat you as equals and authority should only count where it's needed e.g. authorising business decisions, dealing with disciplinary matters etc.

Comment: @roganjosh it's a rule due to the power discrepancy. Yes, you could probably get somebody a gift for a special occasion even if they are "above" you but the general rule is there to not make this a habit. Because it *is* chilling of bosses expect to be showered with gifts on the implicit threat that those under them might suffer some sort of retaliation. This is what the power discrepancy is. It might never happen, sure, but there no way to ensure that one won't miss a promotion or be treated worse just because they haven't sent gifts. Therefore good bosses know not to set such expectations.

Comment: > _Because it is chilling **i**f bosses expect to be showered with gifts on the implicit threat that those under them might suffer some sort of retaliation..._  actually I would see this the other way: gifts to senior people can look like bribery for favours (hence things being relaxed for e.g. retirement gifts - see o.m.'s answer).

Comment: @VLAZ when did I say there was any "expectation" on behalf of the boss? We must just have very different working dynamics in our jobs. When I buy a gift it's because I choose to; my bosses in the past actually put themselves on the line to help me out. I _choose_ to say "thank you"

Comment: @roganjosh you didn't. You asked why is the expectation for gifts to not go "up" the chain. That's the reason - because if done often it implicitly sets up the expectation that bosses *should* be given gifts.

Comment: @roganjosh This here is a post about someone showing why this rule is very important: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/193073/12607 These types of rules aren't there to prevent abuse by good employees and good bosses, it's to prevent people turning into bad employees and bad bosses.

Comment: @roganjosh your experience is bizarre, even unusual. It's completely normal in the UK that there are literally HR rules in place preventing gift giving to anyone more senior.  And your question "why why" is a bit unusual in this day and age; in the UK (perhaps only more so in the US) all companies live in fear and terror of unequal authority chains etc

Answer (score 13):

Where I work, a mid-sized company in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), it is common for co-workers to give signed cards and possibly small gifts to people who are leaving and especially to people who are retiring. Often the team joins efforts for a common gift and card with dozens of signatures.

Once someone is leaving, certain rules of propriety alter. It is considered OK to give a small gift to someone who is more senior, especially after a long and cordial relationship. Basically, one cannot bribe someone who has already handed over all management responsibilities, and the customary amounts are so low (single-digit € per contributor) that one does not think in these terms, anyway.

Comment: @Fattie, quite possible to add a box of chocolates, or something for a hobby, or something like that. But yes, the card is the starting point. With as many signatures and personal messages as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Some folks will find the concept of a boss who is also a friend unbelievable. But it does happen.

The main reason *not* to give a gift to a superior, assuming you would do so even if they weren't your boss, is because it might come across as an attempt to curry favor, "suck up", or otherwise purchase favorable treatment you wouldn't otherwise be entitled to.

But infrequent small gifts that you would give any other friend shouldn't be a problem. How you define occasional and small is a judgement call, but I'd say something on the order of picking up the lunch tab a few times a year is harmless, especially if they've been buying your lunch on occasion without submitting it as a business expense.

And in this case, where they're on their way out the door, it's pretty obvious that the gift is *not* a bribe or quid pro quo. So most of the concerns don't apply.

If it's something you would do if they were your peer rather than your boss, and it isn't so extravagant that it will be embarrassing, I'd say go for it. Maybe even talk to the rest of your team about whether folks might want to make it a group gift (with who contributed how much not being disclosed, and everyone invited to sign the card whether they contributed or not so there isn't pressure to get involved.)

Answer (score -11):

> One of the **owners** of the company I work for ...

---

I would honestly recommend ***a thank you card*** (ie, a "Hallmark" type card).

Any sort of gift is somewhat strange.

***No matter how nice the person is***, you're an employee and they're an owner.

Which means:

Say you worked there 10 years and were paid for example $1m in total. Through your work, the owner would have made tens of millions of dollars.

Once you realize that, the idea of gifting an owner, is both fatuous and bizarre, and indeed extremely misguided.

Keep things business-like.

To repeat:

***No matter how nice the person is***, you're an employee and they're an owner.

To repeat:

The owner would have made vastly more from your work than you were paid for your work.

---

### Footnote about owners "retiring" ...

When an owner "retires" from a business, that means the business has "worked out" for the owner - to wit, **the owner now continuously, forever, gets money weekly from the business and does nothing**. IE the owner no longer needs to show up every day and now **does nothing, continuously forever getting (a lot) of money due to the ongoing work of the employees**.

Realizing this, you can see it's doubly-bizarre that an employee would give gifts to an owner.

Comment: While the attitude you describe may well fit many managers or owners, it 100% does not fit all of them. It doesn't fit me. I considered many of my staff friends and cared about many more of them. They were never cogs. You can be as cynical as you like -- it's your loss -- but when you present your cynicism as absolute truth and then base advice on it, I consider that bad advice.

Comment: Having worked for some scumbags, and for some good friends, and for entrepreneurs who made $millions, and for entrepreneurs who lost everything they put into their companies... I think this is a story in your head, not a fact.

Comment: Hi Kate!  The question is about, and the answer is about, owners.  (Employees who are given a "manager" label - - - are employees.)  Secondly you mention cynicism. I'm a singularly non-cynical person; if you find the reality outlined here as cynical, that's a reflection on your own outlook.

Comment: HI @Spike0xff - every person here would have worked for the four categories of owner you mention.  In all four cases, do not give them gifts.

Comment: The question didn't mention that their "boss" was necessarily the owner or one of the stakeholders of the organization, "boss" might also mean their manager. And even if it did mean the owner, I cannot bring myself to agree with your answer entirely. I do see that what you mention is the case a lot of times, perhaps even the majority of them, but I think that the OP themselves know their boss better. Their question is not much regarding the boss' way of viewing employees, it's more regarding if they should give them a book as a gift or not *when they are retiring*, which you may have missed-

Comment: as I do not think that the employee would have as much value to the boss when he is retiring. Your point would have made more sense, considering all the other mentioned factors aligned with it, if the boss would be their active boss and not about to retire.

Comment: Do you somehow think I'm not an owner? Based on what, I wonder. You think I considered my staff all cogs. You're **wrong** and furthermore, cynical. But as I said already, that's your loss and doesn't affect my life or the way I feel about people who worked for me and helped me make or lose money while being paid fairly themselves.

Comment: hi @SyedM.Sannan!  please read the **first four words** of the question!

Comment: "You think I considered my staff all cogs." There are two issues here (1) Obviously there are exceptions to everything, so, nothing to discuss on that front. (2) Whilst you report you, yourself, didn't "think of" the folks as cogs. So, that's a case of great / how charming / etc. Setting aside how you thought of them, they were, in fact, cogs. And the owners did, in fact, **make spectacularly more money from the cogs than the cogs were paid**. (Unless the business was a flop, or just a novelty effort. The entire nature of a business is that it makes far more from each employee than paid to..

Comment: .. employees.) (In the ultimate example, public companies and the major founders of public companies are worth "spectacularly" more than was paid to the employees).  Thus, a gripe with my answer may be that the answer emphasizes "how the owner thinks" ("they are cogs").  (A) in the overwhelming number of cases that is precisely how owners think.  (B) Completely setting aside emotions and thoughts, the employees make (usually spectacularly) less than the amount money they generate for the owners. Gift giving to owners, *even the "nicest" of owners who "think" some certain way* is bizarre.

Comment: Good answer. It's good to resist the temptation to be 'grateful' for our bosses for treating us nicely while they profit from our labour

Comment: -1 While the dynamic between owner and employee might be true to some extent, the answer massively fails to acknowledge risks on the side of the owners. If the company goes south, employees just walk out and get another job while owners have to deal with the failure and probably loss of money of the company. And overall, a bit of niceness and positivity goes a long way. Answer spreading negativity always need a -1.

Comment: @Fattie you must of had a really bad experience or you are projective your own negative mindset for fun. A gift is a personal gesture, not a business one. OP wants to give a gift to a **PERSON, NOT A MANAGER**. It is a simple token of gratitude. You focus too much on the money aspect of things. Of course the owner will make more than the employee, it is a company, not a charity.

Comment: @CodeJunkie note the first four words of the question. Giving a company *owner* a gift is an embarrassing and silly idea.  Perhaps embarrassing is not quite the right word - it's sort of "oddball, weird and strange". I wouldn't even know how to respond if someone who worked for me freelance or for a business of mine "offered me a gift". {I'd probably sort of wave it off and say "How sweet, you keep that but I'll take your thanks, have a good day..." For example, if someone I knew heard I was *accepting gifts* froim people who work for me, they'd think I was a fruitcake.}

Comment: There is a good answer in here, but it's hidden under all the attitude that no one could possibly think differently to the answerer and they must be stupid if they don't ("silly", "embarrassing", "fatuous", "doubly-bizarre")

Comment: @mattfreake I understand what you're saying, but it would be literally "embarrassing"  if someone who worked for me offered me a gift, and it's strange enough that "bizarre" fits.  Fatuous is a bit fatuous.  :O

Comment: @Fattie, why would it be _it's sort of "oddball, weird and strange"_ ? A person is providing a small token of gratitude, maybe they appreciate something you did or you were simply nice. It is an interpersonal thing and not any kind of business based interaction. It does not matter who the person receiving the gift is. I am really wondering why your OG answer is obsessed with the financial gain ? You are viewing employees as tools to make money which is kinda, and no offense, sick.

Comment: It's a one-off retirement gift, it's not a birthday one. It *could* be “fatuous and bizarre” (your words) to give an employer a gift every year because it was their birthday. But the person retiring will (or should) feel pleasantly surprised and appreciative.

Comment: @CodeJunkie - employees are tools to make money.  Mari-Lout - it's a company owner; "retirement" just means "Oh good, now I can make plenty of money from the workers, and not even bother showing up."

Comment: @Fattie I really hope the people working for you realize that in time and they all leave. You should not be working with people.

Comment: @CodeJunkie unfortunately, and conversely, based on you comments, you're the type of employee who (unfortunately) gets "taken for granted" and, in a word, is tricked in to believing that companies exist for any reason other than to make huge amounts of money (for the founders) via paying relatively very small amounts of money to employees.

Comment: Just FTR people absolutely love working for me - for the simple reason that **I pay incredibly well**. However - *as I tell everyone openly* - that is a pure trick, it's a way to get *more effective* employees working for me.  (Put it this way, an owner can extract 10x the money paid to an "ok" worker from an "ok" worker - but - in many fields, an owner can extract proportionately far more from a high-performance worker; in the example of "10x" from an "ok" worker, you might pay a whole 2x ("wow! imagine!") to a high performance worker, but extract 50x the return.)

Comment: @Fattie it seems your are still only focused on the financial aspect of things.  Financial status and or gain has nothing to do with being human. Basic moral values teach you that. **If someone is presenting you a gift, it is out of gratefulness for something you did, it is not a business transaction**.

Comment: The issue is this, *"If someone is presenting you a gift, it is out of gratefulness for something you did ..."* actions can be misguided. There's no need to be "grateful" to a company owner, they have done nothing for you, and indeed, the worker has directed a spectacular, enormous, benefit *to* the owners via their work. None of this is surprising or unusual (indeed, exactly as someone simply commented in one of the answers [in the German milieu I believe] "gifts flow downwards in corporations", which is the completely normal posture.

Comment: Again, the business side of things is not a factor in this. Say you are put in a room with a random person, stripped naked(to eliminate any status clothing etc.). There is no positive way to identify that the person there with you is a company owner without them telling you they are. It is not a manager or owner and a random factory worker. It is simply 2 people. Strip away all the titles, money and status and you are left with a regular person. That is who you are gifting to.

Comment: This answer does not deserve 11 downvotes. The answer is not that bad. His point is a "**Thank-you**" card should be sufficient.

Comment: Job - I supply militant "worker's rights" -type answers. It's not a worker's rights oriented site.  So it goes.  To cut to the chase, the idea of giving a gift to a business owner - is nuts.